# tutorial that install couchnode on couchbase/mac os x&linux

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchnode

I hope to integrate couchnode to my project that make me to access couchbase via nodejs conveniently.
Is there any tutorial that demonstrate how to install couchnode

https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode

the document on the url above does not mention the installation of couchnode

on mac/couchbase

or any person has the experience

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using mainly Mac and it is working perfectly.

The doc mention the Mac using http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/ :

```
brew install libcouchbase
```

Then you just need to do

```
npm install couchbase
```

Comment: yes, but to install couchbase as it is documented in the read me just install libcouchbase first then run npm install couchbase